# Right arrow with Label 'T' pointing from left figure to right figure

Tags: floats, subfloats, arrows

I want to make a right arrow pointing from left figure to right figure.

[image: The desired design]

The following is my current code.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc1.png}
  \caption{Original Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}% 
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc2.png}
  \caption{Jordan Canonical Form of Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Changing Coordinates}
\end{figure}
```

which generates 
[image: Current Code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply reduce your `subfigure`s to `.47\textwidth` and insert something like

```
{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{T}$}
```

between them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.47\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc1.png}
  \caption{Original Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}%
{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{T}$}%
\begin{subfigure}{.47\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc2.png}
  \caption{Jordan Canonical Form of Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Changing Coordinates}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an attempt using `tikz`. This allows you to customize the arrow style and the position of `T`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.47\textwidth}
  \centering
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (a){\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \caption{Original Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.47\textwidth}
  \centering
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (b){\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
  \caption{Jordan Canonical Form of Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[line width=2pt,-stealth,magenta] ([xshift=2mm]a.east) -- ([xshift=-2mm]b.west)node[midway,above,text=black,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily] {T};
\caption{Changing Coordinates}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc1.png}
  \caption{Original Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}% 
\hsmash{\scalebox{2.7}{\stackon{$\rightarrow$}{\scriptsize\textsf{T\,}}}}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{2D/cc2.png}
  \caption{Jordan Canonical Form of Matrix, $A$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Changing Coordinates}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]